# XNA 4: GetData from Texture2D and Set it into Texture3D with specific order

Tags: xna, color, texture-atlas

I am trying to convert my color grading 2d lookup texture into 3d LUT. When I simply use:

```
ColorAtlas.GetData(data);
ColorAtlas3D.SetData(data);
```

I get this:

[image]

I tried building my 2d atlass horizontally but it did not helped - the data was messed up in a different way.

So my question is how can I influence the order of the data I get from the 2d atlas and how can I properly pass it into my 3d atlas?

Update: I know that I can GetData from a specific Rectangular area and put it into several arrays, but the result is still the same. This is what I tried:

```
        Color[] data2D = new Color[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            Color[] data = new Color[32 * 32];
            GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

            ColorAtlas.GetData(0, new Rectangle(0, i*32, 32, 32), data, 0, data.Length);

            int oldLength = data2D.Length;

            Array.Resize<Color>(ref data2D, oldLength + data.Length);
            Array.Copy(data, 0, data2D, oldLength, data.Length);
        }
        ColorAtlas3D.SetData(data2D);
```

Comment: What you have look right to me. It might be worth trying copying across the data level by level rather than buffering it in an array.

Comment: What do you mean? Right now all I am doing is trying different combinations of reading data from the 2d texture to find the one that will fit into the 3d one properly.

Comment: I don't think you can copy the data level by level. The 2d texture does not know about levels and the 3d one only accepts 1 dimensional array of data.

Comment: At the moment you're reading out the data, buffering it up in an array and then writing it all in one go. I'm not sure why that isn't working, but I think it might be worthwhile trying reading the data (in 32x32 sections) and then writing those sections to the Texture3D straight away (there's an overload of setdata for that).

Comment: I tried doing this in a loop: ColorAtlas3D.SetData(data, i*32, data.Length); right after ColorAtlas.GetData(0, new Rectangle(0, i*32, 32, 32), data, 0, data.Length); and it shows an error "The size of the data passed in is too large or too small for this resource."

Answer (score 1):

You were right, Martin. The SurfaceFormat settings were off in the 2d texture. But for anyone wondering, here is a quick map how GetData/SetData works for the default GetData(data)/SetData(data):
[image]

So basically your layers should be located BELOW your first picture in the 2d atlass to put them into the 3d texture seamlessly.